# Setting custom error message in Array Bag

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

I want to redirect to view if a certain condition is not met. Check code:

```
if($request->get('files') == 'yes' && $request->file('file_name') == null){
                return Redirect::to('brief/'.$id."/edit")
                ->withErrors('errors',"Mention file")
                ->withInput();
            }
```

It prints array as:

```
Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#239
  #bags: array:1 [
    "Mention file" => Illuminate\Support\MessageBag {#240
      #messages: array:1 [
        0 => array:1 [
          0 => "errors"
        ]
      ]
      #format: ":message"
    }
  ]
```

At view end I am doing:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
                <div style="margin-top: 10%;" class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif
```

It is not printing the message **Mention File**

Comment: Do you have a code like `Validator::make($inputs, $rules)`?

Comment: @aldrin27 Yes I have but since this code is not like part of main validator so I am redirecting it separately.

Comment: Can I see how you validate your data's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you pass a string with `->withErrors`, or pass an array with a key "errors" using `->with`:

```
if($request->get('files') == 'yes' && $request->file('file_name') == null){
            return Redirect::to('brief/'.$id."/edit")
            ->withErrors("Mention file")
            ->withInput();
        }
```

or

```
if($request->get('files') == 'yes' && $request->file('file_name') == null){
            return Redirect::to('brief/'.$id."/edit")
            ->with(["errors" => "Mention file"])
            ->withInput();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue.

From the documents:

> you may use the withErrors method to flash the error messages to the
>   session. When using this method, the $errors variable will
>   automatically be shared with your views after redirection,

So `->withErrors('errors',"Mention file")` is actually converting `$errors` into a string which messing things up. Doing simply `->withErrors("Mention file")` just added the message in `ErrorBag`. So the correct code should be:

```
if($request->get('files') == 'yes' && $request->file('file_name') == null){
                return Redirect::to('brief/'.$id."/edit")
                ->withErrors("Mention file")
                ->withInput();
            }
```